# How to sort list into clumps of given size?

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm, sorting, logic

I am trying to create a method that sorts a list of variables into clumps of size four, with the same characters grouped together and in the same order as they are given. You may assume the only given characters are a, b, and c. For example, here I would like to sort myInitialList.

```
myInitialList = ['b1', 'c1', 'b2', 'c2', 'c3', 'b3', 'c4', 'a1', 'b4', 'b5', 'a2', 'c5', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'c6', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8','a9']

endList = clumpsSize4(myInitialList)

print(endList)
```

This should output the result:

```
['a1','a2','a3','a4','b1','b2','b3','b4','c1','c2','c3','c4','a5','a6','a7','a8','b5','c5','c6','a9']
```

How do I write the clumpsSize4 method?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient, but here is my attempt.  Sort the input.  Have one default dict `groupNums` which links a letter to the current number clump it is on.   Have another default dict `groups` which contains the actual clumps.  Sort the groups at the end, iterate over them and join:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def clump(l, size=4):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    groupNums = defaultdict(int)
    
    l = sorted(l)
    for i in l:
        letter = i[0]
        key = str(groupNums[letter]) + letter
        groups[key].append(i)
        if len(groups[key]) == size:
            groupNums[letter] += 1
    
    result = []
    for _, g in sorted(groups.items()):
            result += g
    return result
```